# Magento2 How to Stop Regenarate Product image in localsystem

Tags: magento2.4.5, amazon-web-services, amazon

We have use Amazon web server in my magento,my all product images is load(Frontend) from amazon web server.
but we have create a new product in backend that time my local system regenarate product image.
can we stop regenarate product images?

Comment: So, you need to stop image generate in you local system, I am right ?